# How to use substrin and instr together pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use substring and instr function together to extract the substring but not being able to do so. I tried using pyspark native functions and udf , but getting an error as "Column is not iterable". Can you please help

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [
{"chargedate":"2019-01-30"},
{"chargedate":"2019-02-28"},
{"chargedate":"2019-03-30"},
{"chargedate":"2019-04-29"}
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x : x.find("01",1),IntegerType())
##1st way
##df.withColumn("Chargemonth",substring(df.chargedate,1,instr(col("chargedate"),'01'))).show()
##2nd way with udf
df.withColumn("Chargemonth",substring(df.chargedate,1,udf(col("chargedate")))).show()
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? If you just need to extract month use `date_format` : `df.withColumn("chargemonth", date_format(to_date(col("chargedate")), "MM")).show() `

Comment: Thank you for your response , However this is a dummy data sample actual data is diff , I want to use it like SQL substring ( string , 1 , charindex (search expression, string ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the function `substring` which requires `(Column, int, int)` but you pass `(Column, int, Column)` that why you get the error:

> Column is not iterable

As I said in the comment if you just need to extract month from date you'd better use builtin function `date_format`. When you can avoid UDF do it.

For you question on how to use `substring ( string , 1 , charindex (search expression, string ))` like in SQL Server, you can do it as folows:

```
df.withColumn("Chargemonth", col("chargedate").substr(lit(1), instr(col("chargedate"), '01'))).show()
```

Use column function [`substr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.Column.substr)

**Note:** `instr` will return the first index of occurrence, maybe that's not what you want.

Comment: Thank you again , Wat I am not gettin is why substring is not working. As you sted substring requires (Column, int, int) and that is what I am passing. so why still I am getting an error.Can you please point me where I am going wrong ? I have edited original post to show wat instr returns and its an integer value so it should work.

Comment: No, I think you're confusing `Column` object and type of column. Indeed the type of that column is integer but when you call the `substring` function you're passing a `Column` and not int.

Comment: I am marking it as answered however I am still confused as return value of instr is integer. Any pointer where I can check difference between substring and substr functions ?

Comment: `substr` is function of  `Column` object (see the link provided in the aswer). [`substring`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring) is sql function which takes a column and 2 integers.